# Cropping a binary column using SQL query

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, binary-data

I have a few tables, each with a binary column with a specific size, (i.e 8 bytes, 16 bytes, 32 bytes, etc.) and a size column indicating the actual data size in that binary column, i want to move all the rows into a varbinary(MAX) table.

example:
[image: binary data example]

I am looking for an SQL query that will transfer the contents of the table into a new table with varbinary(MAX) column, but it will have to crop the data to the specified size.
for instance, something similar to this possible:
`INSERT INTO newVarBinaryTable (new_id, new_data) select (id, newData = crop(data, size)) FROM oldBinaryTable`

Note: My DB is on SQL Server 2008

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
INSERT INTO newVarBinaryTable 
    (new_id, new_data) 
    select id, cast(left(data, size) as varbinary(max))
        FROM oldBinaryTable
```

Answer (score 1):

[Substring](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187748.aspx) works for binary columns. In your case you would need the expression

```
SUBSTRING(data, 1, size)
```

Answer (score 1):

**Note** An 8-byte binary(8) column would be 0x1122334455667788 instead of 0x12345678.  Each byte has 2 hex chars.

You can just use substring, if you already have a column "size"

```
declare @t table (id int identity, bin binary(8), size int)
insert @t select  0x0102030405060708, 8
insert @t select  0x0102030405000000, 5
insert @t select  0x0102030405060000, 6
insert @t select  0x0102030405060700, 7
insert @t select  0x0102030405060708, 8

select id, CONVERT(varbinary(max), substring(bin, 1, size)) as newbin
from @t
order by id
```

Output

```
id          newbin
----------- ---------------------
1           0x0102030405060708
2           0x0102030405
3           0x010203040506
4           0x01020304050607
5           0x0102030405060708
```

For your data

```
INSERT INTO newVarBinaryTable (new_id, new_data)
select id, substring(data, 1, size)
FROM oldBinaryTable
```